# Why isn't this z-index working?

Tags: html, css

I have a pen I'm messing around with. In the end there's going to be an animated sun that travels along the path of the sun_path div, so that when you click "Make it Shine" the sun follows the path up from behind the grass and stops at the apex. The 3 divs in question are the `<sky>`, `<sun_path>`, and `<grass>` divs.

Can anyone tell me why the sun path is not displaying behind the grass and in front of the sky?

Here's the link to [the pen](http://codepen.io/JML/pen/HgIGr).

Comment: Please add your code to the question, simply linking to it is not enough. If the content of the link were to change/move/be deleted this question would be meaningless to future users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typos lines 16 and 69  CSS :

```
 position: relative;
```

not postion: relative;

Comment: Wow thanks! I probably should have ran it through a spell check. Can't believe I missed that and how much time I spent trying to figure out what was wrong. Thanks again.